# How to use Flutter 2.2 background service workers for web

Tags: flutter, dart

Today I see that [many articles](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-2-2-at-google-i-o-2021-92f0fcbd7ef9) were released about Flutter 2.2 and its new functionality. One of them is background caching using service workers. Has anyone an idea of what does it mean and how to use it?

> for web apps, we offer background caching using service workers

UPDATE:

Ok I've found some information in [this](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-2-2-fd00c65e2039) article

> Flutter’s newest stable platform, web, has been improved in this release.
> To start, we’ve optimized caching behavior with a new service worker-loading mechanism, and fixed double-downloading of main.dart.js. In previous versions of Flutter web, the service worker downloaded updates to your app in the background while giving your user access to the stale version of your app. Once that update was downloaded, the user wouldn’t see those changes until they refreshed the browser page a couple times. As of Flutter 2.2, when the new service worker detects a change, the user will wait until the updates are downloaded to use the app, but then they’ll see the updates without requiring a second manual refresh of the page.